# Instead of images, the upvote button, downvote button and upvote/downvote box should use polygonal CSS for the triangles

Tags: discussion, design

This will make customisation of sites easier.
Currently, the following image is used:
[Triangle](http://sstatic.net/mso/Img/stats-arrow.png)

*This uses only HTML and CSS and is supported by all "current" browsers (including IE6.0!)*

http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/image_free_css_tooltip_pointers_a_use_for_polygonal_css/

Screenshots from different browsers:

http://browsershots.org/http://tantek.com/CSS/Examples/polygons.html

Comment: As an aside: I assume that for most browsers the actual rendering is better than [the screenshots](http://api.browsershots.org/png/original/d7/d71c9cbbd2cdcae8f458f4da347e972b.png) at browsershots.org. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An interesting tip, but I think we want more control of the look for future sites.. until SVG is supported in HTML/CSS I don't think we're there yet.

Comment: @aviraldg yes, I made this decision [Like a Boss](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NisCkxU544c)

Comment: Please tell me no one is using IE6 to access SO.

Comment: @uncle brad: I was several weeks at a new job before I was granted local admin privileges.  During that time I was forced to access SO with IE6.  I thought about submitting several bug reports, but I'm sure Microsoft would have just told me to upgrade.

Comment: @Bill, I'm so sorry. I trust you weren't permanently damaged.

Answer (score 2):

It might just be Safari on a Mac (my other browsers render fine), but I find the anti-aliasing of the CSS version quite ugly...

[image: Example of ugly rendering]

Hence: no, please.

Comment: Renders fine in Chrome, Firefox, Safari (the ones I tested)...

Comment: Ah, @Aviraldg, you're right. On my Mac only Safari renders this horrible.

Comment: I'm on windows.

Answer (score 0):

There are many Stack Exchanges by now...

[image: Gaming] [image: Webapps] [image: Photography] [image: Tex]

...what is the advantage of SVG'ing all of these?

Comment: When I made this post, *all* StackExchange sites looked "the same" (a la Windows XP's themes) (SE 1.0)... so, that still made sense back then. And I was not talking about "SVGing" all of them.

Comment: @Aviral Then you want to increase the number of HTTP requests on the site :)

Comment: The technique described above **does not** make any HTTP requests to the server.